# Entity Framework - Inheritance with .Include?

Tags: entity-framework

I think that there's a similar post on here about this but not exactly the same...

I have two entities in my EF model - let's call them Person and Developer, with the latter inheriting from the former.

I also have an association on Developer called Qualifications. This is not visible on the Person entity.

If I'm writing a query against the context, how do I automatically .Include () the Qualifications of the Developer e.g.

**from employee in context.Employee
.Include ("Qualifications")
select employee**

doesn't work... EF complains that the relationship does not exist (I assume because it does not exist on Employee - but there's no Developer entity on the context, just Employee).

Answer (score 14):

I've come across this problem and experimented a little. Here is what i found worked using LINQ 2 Entity.

Say we have in your example Person <-- Developer ---- Qualifications.

If you would like to select a Developer with Qualifications included, you would do this.

```
var dev = (from d in context.Persons.OfType<Developer>
                            .Include("Qualifications")
          where d.ID == id
          select d).FirstOfDefault();
```

Now lets say we have another association between Person and Address, we can also include Address into the select also using LINQ 2 Entity.

```
var dev = (from d in context.Persons
                            .Include("Address")
                            .OfType<Developer>()
                            .Include("Qualifications")
          where d.ID == id
          select d).FirstOfDefault();
```

Notice how I have included the things I needed before I converted the Type and also included again after the conversion. Both includes should now work together without any problems. I have tested these methods and they both work. I hope they work for you given you have your inheritance setup correctly.

GL.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
var results = from developer in ctx.Employee.OfType<Developer>()
              select new {developer, Qualifications = developer.Qualifications};
```

To things are interesting here:

1. we are excluding employees that
   aren't Developers
2. we are then projecting their Qualifications, and
   as a side effect of that projection,
   something called fixup with fill each
   developer.Qualifications too. I.e.
   this is another way of achieve the
   same effect as Include().

if you subsequently do this:

```
var developers = from anon in developers.AsEnumerable()
                 select anon.Developer;
```

You will get just developers, and they will have their Qualifications loaded too.

See [Tip 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/02/25/tip-1-sorting-relationships-in-entity-framework.aspx) for more info on why this works

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion. I will try that out! It sounds a bit like this isn't an "officially supported" solution though from that link you provided, though.

I've gotten around it temporarily by calling Load on the child collection, but this results in a separate SQL call so I'm keen to avoid it if possible.

Thanks again.

Comment: Although one thing I've just realised - the method that this code lives in should be able to work with both derived and non-derived classes i.e. I should get back a collection of Employees, of which some may be developers (who should then have their Qualifications filled in).

Comment: The bit that isn't officially supported on the link was the Sorting of the collection. The actual loading of the collection (all that is used above) is fully supported.

Comment: I find it amazing that such basic feature doesn't exist in EF.
The major problem is that i am facing is that if i want to return ALL employees BUT still get the Qualifications loaded for the developers, by doing:
Qualifications = (developer is Developer) ? (developer as developer).Qualifications : null)

i get Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

What a are my options?!

Answer (score 3):

Based on Tri Q's answer, but for the ones that prefer the '.Load()' approach, you can use:

```
context.Persons.OfType<Developer>().Include(t => t.Qualifications).Load();
```

I use it inside my DbContext. I created LoadDb() method, that loads all the data I need. So I can use it from many projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EF but this looks to me like a standard inheritance problem. If you want to access the unique properties of a child class from a collection of 'parent' objects (where the actual objects may or may not be instances of the child class) then you need to check the object type and cast it to the child where appropriate, then you can access the unique properties.

What would you expect the given statement to return if some or all of the objects were person not developer?

Comment: Hi...

It should not try to load in the child entities for the base class, because they don't exist. I do the casting to check the child properties etc. - but the whole point of the include is to read it all in in one go (bear in mind that EF doesn't support lazy loading).

Comment: I think I'd be inclined to not subclass Person but rather create another class called Developer that has-a Person, that way you can probably retrieve a collection of Person and through association be able to retrieve those that are referenced by a Developer and from that Developer object be able to find those with Qualifications. I.m really not sure it's possible to do what you are trying to do using the class hierarchy you have indicated.